# How to map collection properties using reflection

Tags: c#

Hi There I have these source and destination classes and getting stuck at mapping ICollection SomeClasses{get;set} property. I have simplified them but actual classes are quite complex.

```
public class Source
    {
        public string Name{get; set;}
        public ICollection<SomeClass> SomeClasses {get;set}
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public string Name{get; set;}
        public ICollection<SomeClass> SomeClasses {get;set}
    }

    public class SomeClass
    {
        public string Name {get; set;}
        public string SomeThing {get;set}
    }
```

Here is my code I played around with no luck.

```
public object Map(object source, object result)
        {           
            foreach (PropertyInfo item in source.GetType().GetRuntimeProperties())
            {
                if (item.PropertyType.IsGenericType && item.PropertyType.GetInterface(typeof(IEnumerable<>).FullName) != null)
                {
                    Type type = item.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                    var innerObj = FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(type);

                    var listType = typeof(List<>);
                    var constructedListType = listType.MakeGenericType(innerObj.GetType());

                    var newList = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(constructedListType);

                    IEnumerable listValue = (IEnumerable)item.GetValue(source);

                    IEnumerable listValue = (IEnumerable)item.GetValue(source);

                    //newList.Add(innerObj);
                    //item.SetValue(source, newList);

                    foreach (var val in listValue)
                    {
                        newList.Add(val);
                    }

                    //list.Add(obj4);
                    //option a
                    //result.GetType().GetRuntimeProperty(item.Name).SetValue(result, newList);

    //option b
    result.GetType().GetRuntimeProperty(item.Name).SetValue(result, item.GetValue(source));

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: There's a library called AutoMapper that does exactly this. Have you looked into that?

Comment: what exactly are you struggling against? What are the errors you're encountering? Adding more precision as to the specific problems you're facing will yield more and better answers

Comment: @PoweredByOrange Thanks for your suggestion. AutoMapper is great but that requires me to make so many changes to the property names which is not feasible for me because i'll have to go through about 5000 code lines. It is much batter to write own 25 lines here.

Comment: @Louis if I run option a) I get this error message "Object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[Models.SomeClasses ]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection1[Models.SomeClasses ]'."

Comment: @Louis option b) Object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[Models.SomeClasses ]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[Models.SomeClasses ]'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option a) worked for me after changing namespace under which I have defined class SomeClass. Actually SomeClass has been define under to different namespace and I was picking up wrong one.